# Git is not tracking directory after add subtree

Tags: git, heroku, github, git-submodules, git-subtree

I have a directory `dir1` that I wanted to push to heroku instead of my entire git repo. So I decided to use the command `subtree push --prefix dir1 heroku master:master`

I had initially done `git subtree add --prefix dir1 heroku master` which i don't think i wanted to do.

When I run it again it says prefix `'dir1' already exists.`

I am now in a weird spot, not a single change is being tracked in dir1 directory, and this is where my parse-server stuff is ( i am migrating my iOS app currently )